# Gathering data from google analitycs to my own admin panel

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm starting with google analitycs.

Before I'll start implementing this into my pages I'm wondering if I'm able to get informations like average time at site, where my user came from, which devices they are using etc.

I would like to get those information from my VueJS front SPA application by async HTTP GET call and display those there. Is it possible?

If yes I would be very thankful if you provide some links to google API where I can find it or some tutorial.

Comment: Here is a basic example for accessing Core Reporting API with JS. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js

Answer (score 0):

Since Universal GA you can't access users' origin data outside GA in your application. Before that you had all this juicy information inside a cookie, inside __utma, __utmz etc ([more info here](https://www.morevisibility.com/blogs/analytics/from-__utma-to-__utmz-google-analytics-cookies.html)).

The information you're asking about (time on site, pages visited, etc) can be retrieved from GA afterwards if you make use of the [userid](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en) feature.

Comment: I think they want to access the aggregated data not the per-user details.

Comment: Still the same, you don't have any information GA collected in your cookies or environments. Not at runtime anyways. The comment from https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943345/%d0%94%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%91%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85 is helpful if you want that information at another time.